# MongoDB Export with Query

Tags: mongodb

In Mongodb, Mongoexport for collection is working on windows but when use --query getting the below error
Failed: error parsing query as Extended JSON: invalid JSON input

--query="{'CreatedOnUtc' : { '$gt' : ISODate('2021-04-22T08:36:28.869Z')}}"

Comment: Were you able to solve this? Wast that answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

> Provides a query as a JSON document (enclosed in quotes) to return matching documents in the export.
>
> You must enclose the query document in single quotes ('{ ... }') to
> ensure that it does not interact with your shell environment.

As per the [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongoexport/)

Swap the single and double quotes in your query field.

For ex.

```
-q='{ "a": { "$gte": 3 }, "date": { "$lt": { "$date": "2016-01-01T00:00:00.000Z" } } }'
```

Comment: When i try this below query. still have exception '{ "CreatedOnUtc": { "$lt": { "$date": "2016-01-01T00:00:00.000Z" } } }' . Error message: error parsing command line options: too many positional arguments: [CreatedOnUtc: { $lt: { $date: 2016-01-01T00:00:00.000Z } } }']

Comment: I feel something wrong with your characters used for single, double quote. Did you copy paste them? Where are your running this I mean machine OS?

Answer (score 0):

I think the quotes are inverted, try the following

```
--query='{"CreatedOnUtc":{"$gt":ISODate("2021-04-22T08:36:28.869Z")}}'
```